# What are sparse files and how to deal with them?

Tags: linux, df

When dealing with sparse files, `df` appears to report the dummy size and not the apparent size of the file which makes it difficult to monitor free space on the system. (I use `df -h` to check disk usage). How do I deal with these sparse files? If not `df` then what would be the ideal way to check disk usage?

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/581496/195224 might give you some clues.

Answer (score 1):

`df` doesn't report a dummy size but the actual disk space taken by sparse (and non sparse) files. There is no particular reason to monitor/compute the disk usage otherwise.